# Show that linear operator is bounded and calculate its norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $A: \mathcal{C}\left(\left[a,b\right]\right) \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $Af := f(b) - f(a)$. This is a linear functional between the space of continuous functions from the interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ to the reals. I'm supposed to show that $A$ is bounded and calculate its the norm given by

> $\|A\| := \operatorname{sup}\{\; |Af| \; : \; f \in \mathcal{C}\left(\left[a,b\right]\right)\;\;\textrm{and} \;\; \|f\| = 1 \;\}$.

Since $[a,b]$ is a compact set  $\|f\| = 1 \Leftrightarrow \max_{x\in [a,b]} |f(x)| = 1$. I think this implies that for any such $f$ we have that $|Af| = |f(b) - f(a)| \leq 2$. A function, for which this upper bound is attained is given by  $f(x) = sin(x)$ on $[a,b] = [\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}]$. With this in mind I would assume that $\| A \| = 2$. However, this is of course very hand-wavy and I'm not sure if it is correct at all. Also I'm at a loss on how to prove that $A$ is bounded. I know that a continuous function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ must attain its maximum/minimum, so we can give an estimate of $|Af|$ for a particular $f$. But how can this be done for *all* continuous functions on $[a,b]$?

Answer (score 3):

Your proof that $\|A\|\leq 2$ seems correct, since $|Af| \leq |f(b)| + |f(a)| \leq 2$ for every $f$ with $\|f\|\leq 1$.

Choosing $f(x) := \dfrac{2}{b-a}\left(x- \frac{a+b}{2}\right)$ (i.e., $f$ is the affine function in $[a,b]$ such that $f(a) = -1$ and $f(b) = 1$) you have that $|Af| = 2$, hence $\|A\| = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a function
$$
                g(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}1, & t = a, \\ 0, & a < t < b, \\ 1, & t = b,\end{array} \right.
$$
then $g$ is of bounded variation, and your functional $A$ is a Riemann-Stieltjes integral
$$
                 Af = \int_{0}^{1} f(t)dg(t) = f(b)-f(a),\;\;\; f\in C[a,b].
$$
Consequently, $\|A\|=\mbox{Var}(g)$ is the total variation of $g$ on $[a,b]$, which is $2$.